# Monitoring FAN and Temperature of HP server with OID

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I want to monitor HP Proliant DL 350 G2 with Solarwinds, I want to add OID and MIB and monitor HDD, FAN, Power supply status?

I used MIB walker but the response MIB info refers to Windows Server 2003 not HP Server itself?!!

we can see that info through HP Management web console in windows, I want to know where that info come from? Is that application use MIB records or iLO chip??

Comment: http://thwack.com would probably answer you better.

Answer (score 2):

Like EhevuTov said, you'll want to get some management agents that support your hardware.

While terribly convoluted (at least, for me - I'm not very clever), HP does provide management agents that use SNMP and WBEM to provide various systems information.  The management agents are usually part of the Proliant Support Pack, but you can also get just the agents on their own.

A lot of times these agents tie in with a larger offering, like the System Management Homepage, which you mentioned (SMH) or HP Systems Insight Manager (SIM).  If you already have the SMH installed, you probably already have the agents installed, it's simply a matter of configuring them to point to a different tool.  There should be SNMP options on that management homepage (under the Setup drop down).

I've always found deciphering HP's various "bag-o-tricks" to be difficult, but a few of their tools can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find an SNMP agent that supports your hardware in some way or an SNMP agent extension that does.

That agent will then report to your management system that will receive SNMP traffic and decode the traffic with the agent MIB

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your SNMP service is set up correctly. Go to control panel, advanced, services and right click on the SNMP service and make sure everything is set up correctly.